# What does @cc_on mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, conditional-compilation

Sometimes I see `@cc_on` in JavaScript. What does it mean?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's for [conditional compilation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment#Conditional_Comment_in_JScript). Seems to be a feature of Microsoft's "[JScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript)" ECMAScript implementation.

Comment: Not IE but JScript (ECMAScript implementation used in IE). This is important because JScript, for example, is also used in ASP, Windows Script Host, etc. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript