# Conditional comment for IE 8 not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to change the `SRC` attribute of my iFrame for users on IE 8 or less.

Here's my code :

```
  <script>
var i_am_old_ie = false;
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
i_am_old_ie = true;
<![endif]-->
</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
if(i_am_old_ie) {
   $("#shop").attr("src","shopping_cart/browser_support.html"); 
} else {
    $("#shop").attr("src","shopping_cart/index.html"); 
}      
});
</script>
```

It detects that it's IE...but still sends all IE users to `shopping_cart/browser_support.html`. Even if I use IE 9, it will send me there. Same thing for 7, or 8.

But it sends all other users not using IE to `shopping_cart/index.html` (wich is correct).

What's wrong in my code?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't insert the  inside the script tag. It needs to be outside.

```
<script>
var i_am_old_ie = false;
</script>

<!--[if lte IE 8]>

<script>
i_am_old_ie = true;
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned you can not use HTML conditional statements between `<script>` tags.

This should work however:

```
if (document.all && !document.getElementsByClassName) {
    i_am_old_ie = true;
}
```

The above will only run in IE8 or below

Edit:

Some nice examples [LINK](http://tanalin.com/en/articles/ie-version-js/)

Answer (score 1):

There is a different syntax for conditional comments inside JavaScript.  [What does @cc_on mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341460/what-does-cc-on-mean-in-javascript) has details.

[Wikipedia's Conditional comment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment#Conditional%5FComment%5Fin%5FJScript) page has an example of version switching using it.

> ```
> <script>
> /*@cc_on
>
>   @if (@_jscript_version == 10)
>     document.write("You are using IE10");
>
>   @elif (@_jscript_version == 9)
>     document.write("You are using IE9");
>
>   @elif (@_jscript_version == 5.8)
>     document.write("You are using IE8");
>
>   @elif (@_jscript_version == 5.7 && window.XMLHttpRequest)
>     document.write("You are using IE7");
>
>   @elif (@_jscript_version == 5.6 || (@_jscript_version == 5.7 && !window.XMLHttpRequest))
>     document.write("You are using IE6");
>
>   @elif (@_jscript_version == 5.5)
>     document.write("You are using IE5.5");
>
>   @else
>     document.write("You are using IE5 or older");
>
>   @end
>
> @*/
> </script>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Conditional HTML comments only work in HTML.

JavaScript is not HTML.

It's generally not a good idea, and feature detection is reccomended, but if using jQuery you can do:

```
var i_am_old_ie = $.browser.msie && ($.browser.version <= 8);
```